# Does TiDB plan to support window functions?

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions, tidb

TiDB is an hybrid transactional and analytical database. For analytical queries, I find that I often need window functions. I know that TiDB is MySQL-compatible, and that MySQL does not have window functions. But TiDB SQL can have extra features that MySQL SQL does not have, right? As such I wonder if there are plans to support window functions in the future?

Comment: This is StackOverflow and not TiDB Q&A. Maybe if you first read the [roadmap](https://pingcap.com/docs/ROADMAP/) of TiDB you would know the answer

Comment: and this [mailing group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/tidb-user) is probably the most suitable place to ask something like that

Answer (score 1):

TiDB 3.0 supports window function.

Answer (score 0):

As @Simo mentioned, you can see that the Window Function is on the roadmap and it will be available early next year.